# Call nested function based on input parameter

Tags: javascript, closures, nested-function

I have a function like this.

```
function myfun(input1, input2, input3){
    //
    // Other codes which deals with input2 and input3 (irrelevant)
    //
    function a(){
        console.log('func a');
    }
    function b(){
        console.log('func b');
    }
    function c(){
        console.log('func c');
    }
    function d(){
        console.log('func d');
    }
    // input1 is an array
    for(var i=0; i<input1.length; i++){
        var name = input1[i];
        name(); // Doesn't work as 'name' refers to a string;
        this[name](); // Doesn't work;
        // How can i execute the nested function whose name is stored in input array ?
    }
}
myfun(['b','d'], 'foo', 'bar');
```

How can I call the nested functions whose names are given in input1 array?

Thank You.

Comment: Since you have `this[name]();` in your code, have a look at the [MDN article about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), to get a better idea how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

As @Felix suggested, there is a much better way (in terms of efficiency) to do this -

```
var myfun = (function () {
    var util = {
        a: function (){
            console.log('method a');
        },
        b: function (){
            console.log('method b');
        },
        c: function (){
            console.log('method c');
        },
        d: function (){
            console.log('method d');
        }
    };

    return function (input1, input2, input3) {
        for(var i=0; i<input1.length; i++){
            var name = input1[i];
            util[name]();
        }
    };
}());

myfun(['b','d'], 'foo', 'bar');
```

This way the `util` object will be constructed only once, where in the previous way the object will be constructed each time `myfun` is called.

However, please note that in this case, the memory footprint will be larger than the previous one as a reference to `util` will always be stored in the memory because of closure.

---

Rather than creating inner functions, try creating an object with methods -

```
function myfun(input1, input2, input3){
    var util = {
        a: function (){
            console.log('method a');
        },
        b: function (){
            console.log('method b');
        },
        c: function (){
            console.log('method c');
        },
        d: function (){
            console.log('method d');
        }
    };

    for(var i=0; i<input1.length; i++){
        var name = input1[i];
        util[name]();
    }
}

myfun(['b','d'], 'foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: And depending on the nature of those inner functions, you could use an IIFE to create the object only once and still make the functions inaccessible from the outside. E.g. `var myfun = (function() { var util = {}; return function(input1, ...) { ... }; }());`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yup, you're absolutely right, I missed that. Thank you for your input, I've edited my answer!

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

You must make the functions members of an object.

```
var funcFactory = {
    a:function(){
        console.log('func a');
    },
    b:function(){
        console.log('func b');
    },
    c:function(){
        console.log('func c');
    },
    d:function(){
        console.log('func d');
    },
    call:function(input1, input2, input3){     
        for(var i=0; i<input1.length; i++){
           var name = input1[i];
            this[name](); // Doesn't work;
        }
    }
}
funcFactory.call(['b','d'],foo,bar);
```

Comment: Given the OP's code, this would make the functions global, because `this` will refer to `window`. You are **not** making the functions "members" of the outer function.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but as @FelixKling said, it creates this refer to window.

Comment: Ahh, right. You would need them to be in an object {a:function(){}...}

Answer (score 0):

replace the name(); with eval(name + '()');

Comment: I would not suggest `eval` for this. It's better to avoid the habit of using `eval` altogether.